# How can I run Hashicorp Vault docker image with HTTPS on production

Tags: security, command-line-interface, production-environment, hashicorp-vault, vault

I've been trying to run the hashicorp/vault docker image in a production environment with https using docker.

I'm running a node server and using the [hashi-vault-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashi-vault-js) npm package to connect to my vault

I did this in Dev mode and it was pretty easy but not so much in production.

In dev mode, I run:

`sudo docker run --name=dev-vault --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -p 8200:8200 hashicorp/vault:latest server -dev`

Then I export the VAULT_ADDR and VAULT_TOKEN by executing commands in the container's isolation mode.

But this will run it in Dev mode and without a secure SSL/TLS.

From the official docs, I created a vault.hcl and configured everything but it just always seems to want to find a local.json file ....really confused...(I'm new to Hashicorp vault).

So please how do I do this in production but with a secure SSL/TLS and without mlock .

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the docker **entrypoint** command like below to use a custom `vault.hcl` file.

```
vault server -config=/vault/vault.hcl
```

Example `docker-compose.yaml` file (vault.hcl file resides inside `/home/volumes/vault/`)

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  vault:
   image: hashicorp/vault
   container_name: vault
   environment:
      VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
   ports:
      - "8200:8200"
   volumes:
      - /home/volumes/vault/:/vault/:rw
   cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
   entrypoint: vault server -config=/vault/vault.hcl
```